# How to convert Silverlight datgrid to PDF?

Tags: c#, silverlight, gridview, pdf-generation

How to convert Silverlight datgrid to PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two excellent pdf libraries for silverlight [silverlightpdf](http://silverlightpdf.codeplex.com/) and [silverpdf](http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/)..

Answer (score 0):

Here is set of methods which will be usefull for you.

```
public static RenderTargetBitmap ConvertToBitmap(UIElement uiElement, double resolution)
            {
                var scale = resolution / 96d;
                uiElement.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
                var sz = uiElement.DesiredSize;
                var rect = new Rect(sz);
                uiElement.Arrange(rect);
                var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(scale * (rect.Width)), (int)(scale * (rect.Height)), scale * 96, scale * 96, PixelFormats.Default);
                bmp.Render(uiElement);
                return bmp;
            }

    public static string CreatePDF(RenderTargetBitmap bitmap)
            {
                var jpegString = GridImageConverter.CreateJpeg(bitmap);
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat(
                    @"%PDF-1.4
    %");
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat("\u00e2\u00e3\u00cf\u00d3\n");
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat(@"1 0 obj
    <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
    endobj
    2 0 obj
    <</Type/Pages/Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1>>
    endobj
    3 0 obj
    <</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 {0} {1}]/Contents 4 0 R/Resources<</XObject<</Im0 5 0 R>>>>>>
    endobj
    ", (int)(bitmap.Width * 0.75), (int)(bitmap.Height * 0.75));
                int obj4Offset = stringBuilder.Length;
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat(
                    @"4 0 obj
    <</Length 27>>stream
    {0} 0 0 {1} 0 0 cm
    /Im0 Do
    endstream
    endobj
    ", (int)(bitmap.Width * 0.75), (int)(bitmap.Height * 0.75));
                int obj5Offset = stringBuilder.Length;
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat(
                    @"5 0 obj
    <</Length {2}/Filter/DCTDecode/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width {0}/Height {1}/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8>>stream
    {3}
    endstream
    endobj
    ", bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, jpegString.Length, jpegString);
                int xrefOffset = stringBuilder.Length;
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat(
                    @"xref
    1 5
    0000000015 00000 n
    0000000064 00000 n
    0000000118 00000 n
    0000000{0} 00000 n
    0000000{1} 00000 n
    trailer
    <</Size 6/Root 1 0 R>>
    startxref
    {2}
    %%EOF
    ", obj4Offset, obj5Offset, xrefOffset);

                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }

            public static void SaveToPDF(UIElement uiElement, string filePath, double resolution)
            {
                SaveToPDF(ConvertToBitmap(uiElement, resolution), filePath);
            }

            public static void SaveToPDF(RenderTargetBitmap bmp, string filePath)
            {
                if (filePath != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
                        {
                            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.Default))
                            {
                                streamWriter.Write(CreatePDF(bmp));
                                streamWriter.Close();
                            }
                            fileStream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        //handle exception here
                    }
                }
            }
```